# Могу создавать только папки на диске C

Tags: windows

После установки приложения появилось много странных пользователей, по типу Trusted Installer, Все пакеты приложений и т.д. Также из-за этого я могу создавать только папки на диске C, а другие файлы - не могу. Как это исправить?

Comment: Это нормальное поведение системы. Для создания файлов в корневом каталоге системного диска (как и в Program Files, к примеру), требуются привилегии администратора. Не учетная запись администратора, а именно privilege elevation. Для того, чтобы запустить приложение с привилегиями админа, нужно кликнуть на иконку приложения правой кнопкой и выбрать "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откатить систему, т.е. сделать восстановление её.
Для этого идем: Пуск > Все программы > Служебные > Восстановление.

Если много не нужных программ при загрузке Windows, рекомендую открыть msconfig и на первой вкладке поставить галочку "Чистая загрузка Windows только с системными службами".

А по сути, тебе необходимо замести мусор, возьми CCleaner, почисть его, затем удали не используемые программы, после установки которых, у тебя появились эти папки.

Comment: Дело в том, что это была одна программа, которую я удалил, я ради одной программы сносить систему как-то не комильфо. Более того, самая главная проблема не с пользователями, а именно с созданием файлов. Возможно, помог бы возврат настроек к начальным, но я не могу найти такой опции без удаления файлов и программ